# itemStateChanged on JButton

Tags: java, swing, events

I read that a `JButton` implements `ItemSelectable` and into documentation it has the method `addItemListener` so I can argue that it can generate an `ItemEvent`... but when I register with a `JButton` (but also for a `JMenuItem`) that interface the event is not rised?

Why?

I understand that if into docs is reported that a component has an add....Listener it means that it support that event... but for experience isn't often so...

What's the truth?

Comment: What event are you looking for? There is only one event in the ItemListener interface called itemStateChanged(ItemEvent iEvent). Is this the event that is not firing?

Comment: Yes the ItemEvent isn't fired.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between a button being "pressed" (which fires an `ActionEvent`) and a button being "selected" (which fires the `ItemEvent`). By default a `JButton` is backed by a `javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel`. If you look at the `setPressed` and `setSelected` methods in default button model you'll see the code that fires the different events.

So if you programmically call `JButton.setSelected`, your item listener will be fired. If you click the button, you'll only get the action event.

Note also that with a `JButton` (unlike, say, a `JToggleButton`) you probably won't see much visually when it is selected.