# Java: Joptionpane message dialog not opening

Tags: java, message, calculator

I decided to make a neat little calculator program, but now, when I press calculate and run the calculate script, it doesn't open a box stating the answer. I can't find out the problem . Can anyone can please tell me?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame{

    private JTextField text;
    private JTextField text2;
    private JRadioButton plus;
    private JRadioButton divide;
    private JRadioButton multiply;
    private JRadioButton subtract;
    private ButtonGroup group;
    private JButton button;
    private int str = 1;
    private String txt;
    private String txt2;
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int ans;

    public Gui(){

        super("Calculator");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        text = new JTextField(10);
        text2 = new JTextField(10);
        add(text);
        add(text2);
        plus = new JRadioButton("Add", true);
        divide = new JRadioButton("Divide", false);
        multiply = new JRadioButton("Multiply", false);
        subtract = new JRadioButton("Subtract", false);
        group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(plus);
        group.add(divide);
        group.add(multiply);
        group.add(subtract);
        add(plus);
        add(divide);
        add(multiply);
        add(divide);
        add(subtract);
        button = new JButton("Calculate");
        add(button);

        plus.addItemListener(
                new ItemListener(){
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                        str = 1;
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                }
            );
        divide.addItemListener(
                new ItemListener(){
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                        str = 2;
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                }
            );
        multiply.addItemListener(
                new ItemListener(){
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                        str = 3;
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                }
            );
        subtract.addItemListener(
                new ItemListener(){
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                        str = 4;
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                }
            );
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        button.addActionListener(handler);

    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                txt = text.getText();
                txt2 = text2.getText();
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt);
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(txt2);
                if(str==1){
                    ans=num1+num2;
                }
                if(str==2){
                    ans=num1/num2;
                }
                if(str==3){
                    ans=num1*num2;
                }
                if(str==4){
                    ans=num1-num2;
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Answer: %s", ans));

            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the script to run it, if you want it:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gui bucky = new Gui();
        bucky.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        bucky.setSize(300,150);
        bucky.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here's the error code when I click "calculate":

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type Gui.HandlerClass must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

```
at Gui$HandlerClass.actionPerformed(Gui.java:85)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: after some testing it seems to be an issue with the button script

Comment: Change `ActionPerformed` to `actionPerformed`. Spelling and capitalization matter.

Comment: on the item listeners im printing the str into console to check for glitches

Comment: On a side note, why is your running class called `apples`? You probably want to call it something more descriptive, like `CalculatorRunner` or just `Calculator`. The same goes for the `Gui` instance being called `bucky`.

Comment: im doing that cuz im following a tutorial series :P and i got it working everyone thanks fo rthe help!!

Comment: @Aaron: It'd be good if you could accept an answer, because then the question can be removed from the answered list. (You'll also gain two [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) points.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely in your listeners. All your radio buttons are using `ItemListener`s, which is fine, but your JButton is too: the standard listener to use for `JButton` is an `ActionListener`. If you change your `ItemListener` to `ActionListener` (and the event to `ActionEvent`), it should work.

The reason the item event isn't being fired is that [`JButton` only fires the event if `setSelected` is called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709043/732016).

**UPDATE**: The error in your new code is that you put `ActionPerformed` instead of `actionPerformed` as the method name. Case matters.

**UPDATE 2**: Where you declare all your variables, add the following variable:

`private ArrayList<JRadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<JRadioButton>`

You may need to import `java.util.ArrayList` if you haven't already.

Then, below the lines

```
plus = new JRadioButton("Add", true);
divide = new JRadioButton("Divide", false);
multiply = new JRadioButton("Multiply", false);
subtract = new JRadioButton("Subtract", false);
```

add the following:

```
radioButtons.add(plus);
radioButtons.add(divide);
radioButtons.add(multiply);
radioButtons.add(subtract);
```

When you need to check which button is selected, use the following code:

```
for (JRadioButton button : radioButtons) { // Iterate over each button in the list
    if (button.isSelected()) { // If the button is selected...
        // do something
    }
}
```

---

Your other code looks fine, but I would suggest using String constants (or better yet, enums) to manage the +-/* operations. That is, instead of `str = "add"` (et. al.), you should declare the following enum:

```
private enum OperationType {
    ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE;
}
```

and change

```
private String str = "add"
```

to

```
private OperationType op = OperationType.ADD;
```

The outcome of this is that any errors in typing (including a tpyo, or an aCcidental capital) will result in the string being invalid and you'll get weird behavior.

It also means that you can use a `switch` statement: instead of using lots of `if .. else` statements, try this:

```
switch (op):
    case ADD:
        // blah
        break;
    case SUBTRACT:
        // blah
        break;
    case MULTIPLY:
        // blah
        break;
    case DIVIDE:
        // blah
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Error: unsupported operation");
        // or whatever
}
```

This is generally considered cleaner code, and it looks better and is easier to maintain.

Good luck!

Comment: i suck at enumeration i dont understand it do i replace public class gui with private enum OperationType {
    ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE;
} or what?

Comment: No, don't replace it. You can add another class in the same file: just as you have the `HandlerClass` class, add the `OperationType` enum.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run un-compilable code -- **don't do this!**

Instead fix all compilation issues at compile time, and then run only when the code compiles well.

Firstly: You need to capitalize `actionPerformed(...)` correctly.

Next: You shouldn't have *any* listeners on your JRadioButtons. Rather check which button is pressed only in the ActionListener for the main calculate JButton. The reason is you don't care if the user chooses one JRadioButton and then latter changes his mind and chooses another, but rather you only care *which* JRadioButton has been selected when the calculate JButton is pressed.

Comment: Im a java noob i dont know how :P

Comment: @Aaron: you don't know how to do what? Compile?

Comment: To check which button is selected, check the value returned by the method `isSelected()` on all of them. You should probably keep the buttons in an array, and iterate over them - I'll add to my answer.

Comment: @WChargin: no, you don't need to do that. You can easily get the ButtonModel for the selected JRadioButton from the ButtonGroup object. There's no need to place the JRadioButtons in an array.

Comment: @Hovercraft: That's true too; I just always did it that way. I guess that might even be a better way to do it.

Comment: @WChargin: the trick though is to make sure the actionCommand String has been set. This is done automatically for JButtons, but not for JRadioButtons (I'm not sure why). So `setActionCommand(...)` would need to be called first on each JRadioButton for this to work.